# Load a module in python

Tags: python

Create a module in python containing some files and then load those files.

```
import mymodule
var1 = mymodule.load('data/data1')
var2 = mymodule.load('data/data2')
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 import mymodule
>   ----> 2 var1 = mymodule.load('data/data1')
>         3 var2 = mymodule.load('data/data2')
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load'

Comment: The error is pretty much self-explanatory. Do you have a `load` callable on `mymodule`?

Comment: Is `mymodule` a `Python` file or a `class`?

Comment: is a class containing a directory files data1 and data2

Comment: I am not advanced in python, so I don't know how to make load callable mymodule

Comment: @Annalix Did you see my solution? If it has helped you, you can accept my answer by clicking the tick button under the "3" votes on right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`load()` should be like

```
def load(input_values):
    #some logic
    return result
```

and the module `mymodule` is supposed to be a python executable file saved in the same directory as `mymodule.py`

Answer (score 0):

If mymodule is a class, then you need to have a load method if you want to do what you are posting.

Comment: How can `mymodule` be a class when it is imported as shown?